# Sorting List(Of T) stopping early

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting

I have a custom class called SaveFile. One property it has is SaveNumber and I'm trying to sort the list by that property. I read a bunch of articles here and got it to sort properly but it's stopping early? The case in which I noticed this is with set that has 79 saves. It would sort: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, ... 30, 8, 31, ... 70, 9, 71, .. The code I use is

`saveList.Sort(Function(x, y) x.CompareTo(y)`)

But if I use the code:

```
For i = 0 To 3
    saveList.Sort(Function(x, y) x.CompareTo(y))
Next
```

then it sorts right but it takes a very long time and one set has over 700 SaveFiles in it so it takes almost 5 minutes for my program to load. Any ideas?

This is the code that I have for my CompareTo function:

```
Public Function CompareTo(y As SaveFile) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of SaveFile).CompareTo



    'If neither are an autosave then compare save number
    If Not Me.Text.StartsWith("autosave") And Not y.Text.StartsWith("autosave") Then

        If Me.SaveNumber.ToString.Length > y.SaveNumber.ToString.Length Then
            Return False
        ElseIf Me.SaveNumber.ToString.Length < y.SaveNumber.ToString.Length Then
            Return True
        End If

        Return Me.SaveNumber < y.SaveNumber
        'if either is an autosave
    Else
        'Create to comparable integers with
        'a value of 4. We set the value to
        '4 because it is higher than the 3
        'available autosaves, making it sort
        'after any autosaves if only one is
        'an autosave.
        Dim xComp As Integer = 4
        Dim yComp As Integer = 4

        'If x is an autosave then figure out
        'which autosave number it is.
        If Me.Text.StartsWith("autosave") Then
            Select Case True
                Case Me.Text.EndsWith("1")
                    xComp = 1
                Case Me.Text.EndsWith("2")
                    xComp = 2
                Case Me.Text.EndsWith("3")
                    xComp = 3
            End Select
        End If

        'if y is an autosave then figure out
        'which autosave number it Is.
        If y.Text.StartsWith("autosave") Then
            Select Case True
                Case y.Text.EndsWith("1")
                    yComp = 1
                Case y.Text.EndsWith("2")
                    yComp = 2
                Case y.Text.EndsWith("3")
                    yComp = 3
            End Select
        End If

        Return xComp < yComp
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, asking 2 questions in one post is not a good idea because it reduces the chances someone will know the answer to both.  For example, without seeing the code that loads these things or even what they are, makes it just a guess why it takes so long to load.

For the sorting, your `CompareTo` method is flawed.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IComparable%601.CompareTo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true):

> Compares the current instance with another object of the same type and returns an integer that indicates whether the current instance precedes, follows, or occurs in the same position in the sort order as the other object.

That is, it should return -1 (precedes), 1 (follows) or 0 (same).  Yours just returns Boolean:

```
If Me.SaveNumber.ToString.Length > y.SaveNumber.ToString.Length Then
    Return False
ElseIf Me.SaveNumber.ToString.Length < y.SaveNumber.ToString.Length Then
    Return True
End If
...
Return xComp < yComp
```

We have no idea what type `SaveNumber` is, but if it is am integer, comparing the length of the string form if it is not the same as comparing *the value*:

```
' Me vs Other
Return "9".Length < "7".Length
```

That will return `False` (0) when it by value, it should return `1`. Turning on `Option Strict` would have flagged the incorrect return type, which might have led you to the answer.   It should be something like this, ignoring the "auto" logic:

```
Public Function CompareTo(other As SaveItem) As Integer _
                  Implements IComparable(Of SaveItem).CompareTo

    ... special handling for "auto"

    If Me.SaveNumber = other.SaveNumber Then
        Return 0
    ElseIf Me.SaveNumber < other.SaveNumber Then
        Return -1
    Else
        Return 1
    End If

End Function
```

But, you may not even need that (assuming again that `SaveNumber` is an int):

```
saveItems = saveItems.OrderBy(Function(q) q.SaveNumber).ToList()
```

`IComparable.CompareTo()` might be needed in order to handle the "autosave" logic but it might be able to be handled in the `OrderBy()` depending on the information the class exposes.

Comment: That is actually very helpful. The length comparison was because I got tired of 2 coming between 19, and 20. Thank you for explaining CompareTo. I've been trying to understand it and the example I found returned boolean like mine does. I'm sort of learning as I write this program and I think I understand it a lot better now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say, I have to do the CompareTo (as far as I know) because the autosaves absolutely have to be at the top.

Comment: If 2 shows up between 19 and 20 then you were sorting on the form of the number.  `"2"` is more than `"19"` because 2>1 per the [ascii value](http://www.asciitable.com/).  You could use a Natural Sort, but I suspect that the "auto" stuff would not come out as you want. AutoSaves couild maybe be done using  orderby, but a comparer method (need not be IComparable) makes for neater code.

Comment: I got it working. I took what you told me and rewired a lot of it. Now it compares if either of them auto. If not, it compares the SaveNumbers the way you pointed out above and returns an integer of -1, 0, or 1. if one of them is an auto, is says that one first, again, with an integer like it should. If both are autos then it does the same old select case but then computes the return to a proper integer. The help you gave me was perfect and now I understand the CompareTo function worlds better. :D Thank you so much!

Comment: Oops... i updated your post with my fixed code... instead of mine... x.x

Comment: @AlexisShepard - How are you able to edit answers with a rep of only 13?  I thought you needed 2000 to be able to edit posts and answers?